# Get IBOutlet variable name from inside it

Tags: objective-c

I have a `UIImageView` (`ASImageView` is a subclass of `UIImageView`) declared in the header:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ASImageView *imgView;`
Inside my subclass `ASImageView` I have some methods, and, for accessibility purposes, I would like to know the name of the variable - in this case `imgView`.
Is there a way?

Comment: you areasking property?? or else you are asking member description?? print description it will give text,title,frame whatever

Comment: @NHS - I want to get the variable name; as mentioned, in the above case I would like to get `imgView`

Comment: Variables are identify by their addresses not by names. So `XCode` or even any plate form don't know the names of variables. Variables name are for you to identify the object as you can't identify the address.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages objects don't have names. Just because some variable `imgView` references your object, doesn't mean that your object is "called" `imgView`.

And in most C-based languages variable names are not represented in the final executables at all (except for the names of external symbols).

So the short answer is that there's no way to get to that information..

Answer (score 0):

`Variables are identify by their addresses not by names. So XCode or even any plate form don't know the names of variables. Variables name are for you to identify the object as you can't identify the address.`

You can get only `object`'s `class`.
**Example:**

```
BOOL result = [imgView isMemberOfClass:[ASImageView class]];
```

`isMemberOfClass:` returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a given class.

```
BOOL result = [imgView isKindOfClass:[ASImageView class]];
```

`isKindOfClass:` returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.